# How to turn off tooltip for primeng pie chart?

Tags: chart.js, primeng

I am using primeng pie chart, based on chart.js
there are cases that I dont want to display any labels.
In such cases, when I hover over the chart, I get a tooltip display undefined for the label.

In the case of no labels, how do I turn off the tooltips?

Comment: for chart data try:     this.chartData = {
      labels: [], .... and chart options:     this.chartOptions = {
      title: { 
        display: false
      }, tooltips: { 
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },

Comment: works for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

the chart.js has `options` attribute in each chart type so you can customize how you want it to operate.

so in your `html`, add the element

`<p-chart type="doughnut" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>`

and in your `ts` file, add your `options` array where you hold the chart customization. And inside of it, add the customization for `tooltips` as follows:

```
this.options = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  },
}
```

for more info, check [doughnut chart documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)

[tooltip configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)